# C: Getting wrong output which might have to do with null terminator?

Tags: c

I am writing a program that takes an input of chars `*inText`, and shifts each alphabetical character by a certain amount `shift` to create an output of chars `*outText`, (eg. in the case of the `main` function shown below, the input `"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."` should output `Gur dhvpx oebja sbk whzcf bire gur ynml qbt.`, shifting each letter by 13.

The output however, is `aur ~\202vpx o\177|\204{ s|\205 w\202z}\200 |\203r\177 \201ur yn\207\206 q|t.` I don't really know how null terminators work, but I think it may have something to do with the reason for the issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void confab(const char* inText, int shift, char* outText)
{
    // visit each char of inText
    // assign current val of inText to current val of outTextheck
    // if current val of inText is letter, shift the letter
    // go to next char of inText
    outText[0] = '\0';
    while (*inText) {
        *outText = *inText;
        if (isalpha(*inText)) {
            *outText = ((*outText + shift) + '\0');
        }
        (inText++);
        (outText++);
    }
    outText[strlen(outText)] = '\0';
}

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[60] = {0};
    char* s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
    confab(s, 13, buffer);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
}
```

Comment: Note that `outText[strlen(outText)] = '\0';` requires the nul terminator you are writing to be present in the first place!

Comment: Do you mean the part where it says `char buffer[60] = {0};`? I tried seeing if adding `outText[0] = '\0';` at the start of the confab code would do anything, but I don't think it did (in ref to Weather Vane's first comment)

Comment: As one deleted comment said, the buffer is already nul terminated because it was initialised as `char buffer[60] = {0};` so every byte will be set to `0`.

Comment: A word of caution - All the answers mentioned here work only with ASCII encoding of characters which has continuous layout for alphabets. A more portable way would be to maintain an array of 1 shift for each character and apply it `shift` number of times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is in your format part.

You must take care of lowercase or uppercase first.

Check if statement if character is lowercase or uppercase.

```
if (isalpha(*inText)) {
    if (isupper(*outText)) {
        *outText = (((*outText - 'A') + shift) % 26 + 'A');
    } else {
        *outText = (((*outText - 'a') + shift) % 26 + 'a');
    }
}
```

lowercase and uppercase values have different values in ASCII table but they are one after another, meaning letter `b` is just after `a`.

To get your result, you have to first subtract base character (either 'A' or 'a') do the mathematical job and after add again base character.

Later, replace your strlen for null termination with

```
*outText = 0;
```

---

Full code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void confab(const char* inText, int shift, char* outText) {
    // visit each char of inText
    // assign current val of inText to current val of outTextheck
    // if current val of inText is letter, shift the letter
    // go to next char of inText
    outText[0] = '\0';
    while (*inText) {
        *outText = *inText;
        if (isalpha(*inText)) {
            char t = isupper(*outText) ? 'A' : 'a';
            int tmp = (((int)*outText - t) + shift) % 26;
            if (tmp < 0) {
                tmp += 26;
            }
            *outText = tmp + t;
        }
        (inText++);
        (outText++);
    }
    *outText = 0;
}

int main(void) {
    char buffer[60] = {0};
    char* s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
    confab(s, -1, buffer);
    printf("%s\n%s\n", s, buffer);
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. You should also add about the ascii values of alphabets.

Comment: Why do they need to do `*outText = 0;` if the string is already terminated with a NUL? ;)

Comment: @ChrisTurner Ouh dear you who ate all the wise of this world ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it definitely works when `shift` is a positive integer. However when I set `shift` to -13 instead of 13, the output comes out all wrong.

Comment: @RichardHan it is hard to do school work for you. I've updated answer.

Comment: I want to know is it correct that we must allocate memory to `char *s` for example with `malloc()` before assingning to string. is above method cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: @EsmaeelE if you don't modify string later, you are safe. Doing `*s = '1'`; later would case UB. The best is to set like this: `const char* s = "test"`.

Comment: is it true when you just assign string to `chat * s `compiler allocate memory  for `s` and if we try to change `s` contents later maybe go further from allocated memory  and this lead to UB

Comment: @EsmaeelE compiler will allocate memory and put your string to memory somewhere. It can be put to non-volatile memory on some platforms meaning crash if you want to write there (or not, that's why it is *UB*).

Comment: thanks are you have some more link of reference about that?

Answer (score 2):

This is never going to work...

```
outText[strlen(outText)] = '\0';
```

... because `strlen()` needs the string to be null terminated for it to work properly.

But you don't need to do anything as complicated as what you have, since you're already incrementing `outText`, when the loop finishes it's already at the end of the string and you can just do

```
*outText='\0';
```

Also, I'm not sure what the `'\0'` is doing in this line of code, but it's not terminating anything. It'll just be converted into an integer of value 0.

```
*outText = ((*outText + shift) + '\0');
```

What you should probably do is make sure that when you shift the letters they stay as letters like this.

```
*outText = (((*outText-'a') + shift) % 26)+'a';
```

That obviously only works for lowercase letters - you'd need to use `'A'` instead for uppercase letters - you can tell what you've got by using `isupper()` or `islower()` like this and then you won't also need to do the `isalpha()` check as well.

```
if(isupper(*inText)) {
    *outText = (((*outText-'A') + shift) % 26)+'A';
}
else if(islower(*inText)) {
    *outText = (((*outText-'a') + shift) % 26)+'a';
}
```

Comment: @tilz0R that doesn't change the fact that trying to terminate the string using `strlen` is wrong though

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use pointer so it's (I think) easier to understand.

```
void confab(const char* inText, int shift, char* outText) 
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    unsigned char character = '\0';
    while (inText[i] != '\0') 
    {
        if (inText[i] >= 'A' && inText[i] <= 'Z') 
        {
            character = inText[i] + shift;
            if (character > 'Z')
                character = character - 'Z' + 'A' - 1;
            outText[j] = character;
            j++;
        } 
        else if (inText[i] >= 'a' && inText[i] <= 'z') 
        {
            character = inText[i] + shift;
            if (character > 'z')
                character = (character - 'z' + 'a' - 1);
            outText[j] = character;
            j++;
        } 
        else 
        {
            outText[j] = inText[i];
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    outText[j] = '\0';
}
```

unsigned char because its value might because more than 127.
`if (character > 'Z')`
= am I still within the alphabet, if not `character = (character - 'Z' + 'A' - 1);` out of alphabet? start again from A.
At the end of the fuction `outText[j] = '\0';` makes sure that your string is delimited as you want it to be.